# VirtualBox keyboard & mouse not working when installing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox but when I get to the "Who are you?" page all keyboard and mouse input functionality seems to disappear - with exception of the buttons. I can't get past this page.

I'm following the WikiHow guide linked below showing how to install and it recommends using an on screen keyboard. It doesn't properly/correctly tell me how to get the keyboard. In any case the mouse also doesn't work so I can't select the text fields anyway.

[WikiHow guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox)

[Who are you screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGCN5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem on the who are you screen. I was not able to click the back button or input any text. I was able to right click and insert emoji for some reason in one of the text fields, then the mouse and keyboard started working for all the fields and I was able to delete the emoji I put in for my name. Install was normal from there.

Answer (score 0):

I went into BIOS and turned off hardware virtulization

I only tried this on windows 10 but to do it you:

Step 1: open the NEW SETTINGS APP (NOT CONTROL PANEL)

Step 2: go to Update and Security

Step 3: go to recovery

Step 4: Use the advanced startup tool

Step 5: In advanced startup press troubleshoot

Step 6: Press UEFI FIRMWARE SETTINGS

NOTE: YOU ARE ENTERING THE BIOS SETUP. ONLY DO WHAT I SAY IF YOU EVER WANT TO USE WINDOWS AGAIN

Step 7: Search for Hardware Virtualization

Step 8: Switch it OFF

Step 9: Exit and save

Step 10: Cross your fingers you didn't screw up your computer

Have Fun!

Comment: Remember, be careful with BIOS. Mistakes can make the computer break (sorry lol).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My mouse was not working for the text fields, but I noticed it was still working for the <del>fields specifically designed for clicking on them with the mouse,</del> on-screen buttons, like "Back", so I clicked on "Back". That brought me to the page where you could select the timezone. I copied the text of the timezone. Then pressed continue. Then I pasted the timezone for everything (right-click with the mouse). That fixed it for me. After I finished installing Ubuntu, the keyboard worked, so I could change everything to what I wanted then.